Modern manhwa where the female lead gets kidnapped by the male lead
I read this manhwa last year and waited for more chapters to pile up so I can binge read butttt I can't find it now . So the story goes like ,, the female lead was an author and one day she meets a man who was really similar to the ml of her novel. Then somehow they spent the night together and the next day when fl woke up she saw that the man held her hostage.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Are there any science fiction or fantasy elements in this work?  It needs to be on-topic to ask about it here.

Yep it is fantasy ig

Do you mean to say that her kidnapper was from her novel, rather than just resembling him?

If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

@FuzzyBoots I believe yes he was

Can you confirm some details of this story? I'm assuming: 1. The protagonist is from modern times 2. They have sex and aren't just literally "spending the night" 3. The ML is definitely a fictional character, and not just someone resembling her work. 4. The FL ends up in her own novel. Are those accurate?

I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about a science fiction or fantasy work. But if you are looking to identify an on-topic work, please [edit] your question and share more details about its sci-fi or fantasy aspects so that we can better help you. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

Might it be As You Wish, Prince? (Anime Planet link)


As You Wish Prince is a Korean fantasy romance webtoon published in English by Tappytoon.
Yoonsoo is the successful author of a popular fantasy series. Just as she’s about to start work on a new series, Imperial Prince Einzen Kyte, the worst villain she created has kidnapped her into the world of her own story?!

Tappytoon currently lists the work as "expired"

Notice: This comic is no longer available. Previously unlocked chapters can still be accessed from Library in the Subscribed and Recent tabs.

Tapas has since picked up the license. Reading the first two chapters, I see that it doesn't entirely match, since he kidnaps her at their first actual meeting (which is, admittedly, at night).
According to this Reddit post, it is a completed work.

The license was transferred to Tapas: https://tapas.io/series/what-do-you-want-to-be-prince/info
